# Run code as different user to have elevated privileges

Tags: powershell, credentials

I'm deploying a monitoring system, and even though it has a large number of plugins, some need to run as a different user to run right.

So I switched to powershell, but the problem is the same, I have some code that give me access denied, because the user has no elevated privileges.

My question how can I run this code as different user, I tried this

```
$usuario = "myuser@mydomain"
$pass = get-content C:\credential.txt`
$spass = $pass | Convertto-SecureString`
pass = "securepass"`
spass = $pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`
write-host $pass 
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $usuario, $spass

$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = ($UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher())
$Updates = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0").updates
$total = $Updates | measure
$total.count
```

Then how can I pass the credentials to the variables. The problem access denied come from this line

```
$Updates = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0").updates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = ' -file path-to-script.ps1'
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Credential $creds -ArgumentList $args -Verb RunAs
```

Powershell also has -Command which you can use to call a function or cmdlet instead of another script.